# Nav2 Robot Cant Create Valid Plan

Tags: navigation, differential-drive, nav2

I use dwb local planner and Smac2d Global Planner, ı have this error when give nav2 goal and robot starts recovery always.

Can you help me, which parameters related with this.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f962CICoAGLT75KYO0rs9HUC23zFHPi1/view?usp=sharing

https://youtu.be/FFJcxohoERQ

```
 GridBased: failed to create plan, invalid use: Starting point in lethal space! Cannot create feasible plan..
 GridBased: failed to create plan, no valid path found.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Based on your logs, it looks like the robot may be starting in a spot that it can't plan out of. Could you update your post to include relevant screenshots from visualization tools like RViz?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is pretty straight forward. If the starting point of a path is in lethal space, it cannot possibly find a valid path from A->B since any expansion from A is going to be implicitly invalid.

You may want to enable the clear under footprint parameters so that it clears the robot's footprint under the current pose (e.g. since we know its free if you're currently there). That should in effect disable that potential error since you're always free under the current pose. If you still run into issues after that, let me know and we can find a solution.

Comment: Thanks much for reply Steven, 
As I understand I add that parameters in my nav_params.yaml
`obstacle_layer: footprint_clearing_enabled: true`
`scan:`
      `clearing: true`
`voxel_layer:`
        `footprint_clearing_enabled: true`
     `point_cloud:`
          `clearing: true`
And my problem not solving,  by the way I use Smac2D Global Planner.
You can see the navigation logs live in this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hppDQvYpovI

Comment: File a ticket on this on nav2's website please and lets follow up there